# Automator: replace text input not working

Tags: automator, macos, automation, javascript

## What I want to do

I want to create a simple Automator service that:

1. Takes `text` as input from `any application`,
2. Does some logic on given input
3. Replaces the selected input text with the calculated output

## The problem

The `return` value in the JS script does not replace the selected input text. I have no clue why. Does anyone have experience with this?

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12, using Automator 2.7

[image: Automator]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was related to the macOS version. After **updating** to `10.12.1` the text is now being correctly replaced!

---

**Edit**: for those interested in the alphabetic sorting, simply add a `Run Shell Script` block and fill in `sort -f`, like so:

[image: Workflow script with Run Shell Script]

Comment: Please provide demo script for text find and replace. I want to do something like that.

Comment: Sure. I edited my answer above.

Comment: Still interested in find and replace. Automator doesn't seem to have a basic text find and replace action. I could script it but seems so fundamental I'm surprised I can't find anything.

Comment: Ah you were talking about find and replace, my bad. Use the 'Run Javascript' action and make use of the String `replace()` function, check out docs and examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)